# Search User Specific information

Tags: php, search

New to PHP so please be specific.
Once my user logs in they come to a form to submit data.
I would like the user to be able to search for all data entered about them in the past month. From which they could edit or delete if they wish.
What code do I use for this search please. Below is what I have (search not working at all)

```
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
Search: <input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form> 


    <?php

// Check if the form value
// was submitted, if not
// assign a default value
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
    $s = $_GET['search'];
}else{
    $s = "%";
}


//echo $s;

// Connects to the database
mysql_connect("localhost","sample","qwerty") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

// Selects which of the databases to use
mysql_select_db('crm');

// Create and runs the query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hours WHERE employee_id LIKE 'RHilfi'";
//echo $sql;

$results = mysql_query($sql);



echo "<br /><br />";
// Loops though all of the results
while($results_array = mysql_fetch_array($results)){

    /*
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($results_array);
    echo "</pre>";
    */
    //print_r($results_array);
    echo " Employee ID: " . $results_array['employee_id'] . " , Date: " .      $results_array['date'] . " , Rate of Pay: " . $results_array['rate_of_pay'] . " , Hours: " . $results_array['hours'] ." , Amount Due: " . $results_array['amount_due']. " [ <a href=\"edit.php?id=" . $results_array['hours'] . "\">EDIT</a>]";

    /*
    // USE THIS ONE
    echo $results_array['title'] . " by " . $results_array['director'] . " [ <a href=\"edit.php?id=" . $results_array['hours'] . "\">EDIT</a>]";
    */


    echo "<br />";

}
    ?>

    <h1>Submit New Claim</h1>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
Employee ID: <input type="text" name="employee_id">
<br />
Date (yyyy/mm/dd): <input type="text" name="date">
<br />
Rate of Pay: <input type="text" name="rate_of_pay">
<br />
    Hours: <input type="text" name="hours">
<br />
    Amount Due: <input type="text" name="amount_due">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 



    <?php


if(isset($_GET['employee_id'])){
    $employee_id = $_GET['employee_id'];
    $date = $_GET['date'];
    $rate_of_pay = $_GET['rate_of_pay'];
    $hours = $_GET['hours'];
    $amount_due = $_GET['amount_due'];
}else{
    $employee_id = "";
    $date = "";
    $rate_of_pay = "";
    $hours = "";
    $amount_due = "";
}


if(isset($_GET['employee_id'])){
    //echo "INSERT NEW RECORD";
    // INSERT NEW RECORD

    // Connects to the database
    mysql_connect("localhost","sample","qwerty") or die("Error " .  mysqli_error($link));
    // Selects which of the databases to use
    mysql_select_db('crm');

    // Create and runs the query
    // INSERT INTO `sample`.`dvd` (`dvd_id`, `title`, `year`, `director`) VALUES  (NULL, 'title', '1234', 'director'); 
    //$sql = "INSERT INTO crm . 'hours' (employee_id, date, rate_of_pay, hours, amount_due) VALUES (NULL, '$employee_id', '$date', '$rate_of_pay', '$hours', $amount_due)";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO hours (ID, employee_id, date, rate_of_pay, hours, amount_due) VALUES (NULL, '$employee_id', '$date', '$rate_of_pay', '$hours', $amount_due)";
    //echo $sql;
    $results = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "<br /><br />";


    // OPTIONAL
    if(mysql_affected_rows() >= 1){
        echo "<h3>Thank you! You have successfully submitted a claim </h3>";
    }

}

    ?>



<a href="login.php">Log Out</a>
```

Comment: I don't understand your code. But i want to say some points.
1- Use mysqli instead of mysql class.
2- Use php session for your users id.
3- separate your code into some individual functions.
4- For using LIKE in mysql use %your_string%

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli instead and if you're using LIKE in MySQL make it looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hours WHERE employee_id LIKE '%RHilfi%'";
```